# validate using vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a form inside a vue application. `vue2-persian-datepicker` package is used for persian date field. I'm trying to validate fields using `vuelidate` and my problem is that the `pdatepicker` component(which comes from `vue2-persian-datepicker` package) does not fire the `@blur` and `@input` events.

I'm trying to do something like this:

inside template:

```
<pdatepicker
   v-model="date" 
   required 
   :error-messages="dateErrors"
></pdatepicker>
```

script code:

```
import VueTimepicker from 'vue2-timepicker/src/vue-timepicker.vue';

import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  components: {
     VueTimepicker,
  },

  validations: {
    date: {
      required
    },
  }, 

  data() {
    return {
      date: '',
    }
  },

  computed: {
    dateErrors() {
      const errors = []
      if (!this.$v.date.$dirty) return errors
      !this.$v.date.required && errors.push('date is required.');
      return 
    }
  },
```

error says `undefined` does not have `$dirty` method.

Comment: And what is `this.$v?`?

Comment: check vuelidate docs [here](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form) @Daniyal

Comment: ))great answer. I mean log to the console what you get there.

Comment: See answer below. He is not properly binding the validator to the v-model

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library for validation but according to the docs you are referencing your v-model incorrectly. You are never binding it to the validator.

```
<pdatepicker
   v-model="$v.date.$model"
   required 
   :error-messages="dateErrors"
></pdatepicker>
```

Also since you are declaring the validations you should be able to safely remove the required attribute from pdatepicker, unless that component requires the property.

See docs the basic form docs here: https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form look at the HTML of the component,